# Draw video frames as bitmaps to MFC Window

Tags: video, bitmap, mfc

I'm trying to write a preview application using the BlackMagic SDK, but am getting choppy playback. I'm using MFC framework, and subclassing CWnd for my video preview window.

When each frame of video arrives, I do a color conversion to RGB and then call a function to display the RGB bitmap.

```
void VideoPreview::Display(int width, int height, byte* buffer)
{
    __int64 begin = GetTickCount();
    HRESULT     hr;
    CRect       rcRect, statusBarRect;

    GetClientRect (rcRect);

    BITMAPINFO bmInfo;
    ZeroMemory(&bmInfo, sizeof(BITMAPINFO));
    bmInfo.bmiHeader.biSize       = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
    bmInfo.bmiHeader.biBitCount   = 32;
    bmInfo.bmiHeader.biPlanes     = 1;
    bmInfo.bmiHeader.biWidth      = width;
    bmInfo.bmiHeader.biHeight     = -height;

    dc->SetStretchBltMode(COLORONCOLOR);

    int iResult = StretchDIBits(*dc,
        rcRect.left, rcRect.top, rcRect.right, rcRect.bottom,
        0, 0, width, height,
        buffer, &bmInfo, 0, SRCCOPY);
    DWORD dwError;
    if (iResult == 0 || iResult == GDI_ERROR)
    {
        dwError = GetLastError();
    }
    else
        fpsCount++;
    procTimeCount += GetTickCount() - begin;
}
```

What can be done to create smoother video?

**Update**:

I ended up going with Direct2D instead of GDI and have gotten much better performance. The below code is what I'm using now for rendering:

```
    // initialization
HRESULT hr = D2D1CreateFactory(
    D2D1_FACTORY_TYPE_SINGLE_THREADED,
    &pD2DFactory
    );
    // Obtain the size of the drawing area.
RECT rc;
GetClientRect(&rc);

// Create a Direct2D render target              
hr = pD2DFactory->CreateHwndRenderTarget(
    D2D1::RenderTargetProperties(),
    D2D1::HwndRenderTargetProperties(
    this->GetSafeHwnd(),
    D2D1::SizeU(
        1280, 720
        /*rc.right - rc.left,
        rc.bottom - rc.top*/)
        ),
    &pRT);

D2D1_BITMAP_PROPERTIES properties;
properties.pixelFormat = D2D1::PixelFormat(
  DXGI_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM,
  D2D1_ALPHA_MODE_IGNORE);
properties.dpiX = properties.dpiY = 96;
hr = pRT->CreateBitmap(D2D1::SizeU(1280, 720), properties, &pBitmap);
ASSERT(SUCCEEDED(hr));

// per frame code
// buffer is rgb frame
HRESULT hr;
pRT->BeginDraw();
pBitmap->CopyFromMemory(NULL, buffer, width*4);
pRT->DrawBitmap(pBitmap);
pRT->EndDraw();
```

Comment: Doing a frame at a time will lead to choppy video because it's just too slow, even with today's processors. You need to use a video pipeline.

Comment: Well the video needs to be displayed as close to real time as possible. Any suggestions on video pipeline?

Comment: Sorry, if I had a suggestion I'd have left an answer.

Comment: Does using SetDIBits make it faster? Are you sure the bottleneck is here? Have you measured how long it takes to draw a single frame? If all you're after is about 24 fps, I'd say it should be possible with SetDIBits - I've achieved better frame rates than that on computer of 5+ years ago. However they didn't have to do video decoding, hence my question if the bottleneck is really here.

Comment: OpenCV has good Tools to display video.

Answer (score 0):

BlackMagic comes with `DirectShow` video source filters. Use `GraphEditPlus` to generate the rendering code with the BlackMagic filter as video source. The `Renderer` filter can be linked to a `HWND` of your choice. This should give the best performance.

I believe your current implementation will induce more `RAM` and `CPU` usage, even if you use `Direct2D` to blit the buffer.